# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.colorbar'

Tags: matplotlib, upgrade

I tried upgrading my matplotlib to the 3.4.2 version. I first did

```
pip install matplotlib==3.4.2
```

It successfully installed. But when I try and import the package in Jupyter, it gives me an error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.colorbar'
```

I have tried to uninstall `matplotlib` and then install again using

```
pip3 install matplotlib
```

But I get the same error. Also in my Anaconda Navigator window I see the older version 3.3.4 still installed

Comment: Did you restart jupyter?   Also make sure that jupyter is being invoked from the same environment as pip.  A useful trick to make sure `python -m pip install matplotlib` and `python -m jupyter notebook`

Comment: When I try python -m jupyter notebook on my terminal, I get a: No module named jupyter message. Version 3.4.2 is installed however, when I check the version on the terminal

Comment: You seem to have your installs crossed, where `jupyter` is being invoked by a different python instance than your `pip install`.  How did you invoke jupyter? If you do `which jupyter` and `which python` my guess is they will be in different directory trees.

Comment: Yes.  Likely that is the case. But how do I fix it?

Comment: Python -m pip install Jupyter.

Comment: Hmmm...same error. Thanks tons, though!

Answer (score 0):

Install these on notebook anaconda and then the problem will be solved
conda install -c conda-forge matplotlib
conda update -n base -c defaults conda
conda clean --all